# Can anybody suggest some open source of image upload in JSP?

Tags: jsp, image-upload

I want to implement a function that support image upload from client side to server side

I search for long time but I cannot find good source

Although there are many source, but it mainly requires to use servlet.

I don't want to use servlet.

Can anybody suggest some open sources of image upload in JSP for reference?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's your problem with servlets?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [*apache's fileupload*](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/),

> The Commons FileUpload package makes it easy to add robust, high-performance, file upload capability to your servlets and web applications.
>   FileUpload parses HTTP requests which conform to RFC 1867, "Form-based File Upload in HTML". That is, if an HTTP request is submitted using the POST method, and with a content type of "multipart/form-data", then FileUpload can parse that request, and make the results available in a manner easily used by the caller.

You can use this to accept certain image type